# CSS : Drop-Down Menu Position issue?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Here is CSS for Drop down

```
.dropdown-menu {

  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Now If I am adding below code

```
position: relative;
```

In the drop down menu's css it Increase's Window Scroll but it also increase's the Table Row height which looks ugly, See below Screen shot

[image: Issue When Adding Position]

But when I am removing

```
   position: relative;
```

from Drop-down menu css drop down items hide see below image

[image]

Code which creating drop down

```
<listcell style="text-align:center; overflow: inherit;">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <actionmenu>
            <actionmenugroup title=" " accesskey="a" btncolor="btn-link"
                btnClass="btn btn-outline btn-default dropdown-toggle" iconClass="fa fa-gear">
                <actionmenuitem label="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_NSF')}"
                    onClick="@command('doNSFPayment',accountPaymntRec = folderFeePaymentListData)"
                    tooltiptext="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_NSF')}" visible="@load(vm.nsfButton)" iconclass="fa fa-plus" accesskey="a">
                </actionmenuitem>
                <actionmenuitem label="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_REFUND')}"
                    onClick="@command('refundAccountPayment',accountPaymntRec = folderFeePaymentListData)"
                    tooltiptext="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_REFUND')}" visible="@load(vm.refundButton)" iconclass="fa fa-refresh">
                </actionmenuitem>
                <actionmenuitem label="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_VOID')}"
                    onClick="@command('doVoidPayment',voidbill=false,accountPaymntRec = folderFeePaymentListData)"
                    tooltiptext="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_VOID')}" visible="@load(vm.voidButton)" iconclass="fa fa-times" accesskey="r">
                </actionmenuitem>
                <actionmenuitem label="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_VOID_PAYMENT_BILL')}" iconclass="fa fa-times"
                    onClick="@command('doVoidPayment',voidbill=true,accountPaymntRec = folderFeePaymentListData)"
                    tooltiptext="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_VOID_PAYMENT_BILL')}" visible="@load(vm.voidPaymentBillButton)">
                </actionmenuitem>
                <actionmenuitem label="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_ENDORSE')}"
                    onClick="@command('printEndorsement',accountPaymntRec = folderFeePaymentListData)"
                    tooltiptext="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_ENDORSE')}" visible="@load(vm.endorseButton)" />
                <actionmenuitem label="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_TRANS_CARD_REPORT')}"
                    onClick="@command('printPrintTxnCard' ,accountPaymntRec = folderFeePaymentListData)"
                    tooltiptext="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_TRANS_CARD_REPORT')}" visible="@load(vm.transCardReportButton)" />
                <actionmenuitem label="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_PAYMENT_LIST_REPORT')}"
                    onClick="@command('printPaymentList' ,accountPaymntRec = folderFeePaymentListData)"
                    tooltiptext="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_PAYMENT_LIST_REPORT')}" visible="@load(vm.paymentListReportButton)" />
                <actionmenuitem label="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_APPLY_OVER_PAYMENT')}"
                    onClick="@command('applyOverPayment',accountPaymntRec = folderFeePaymentListData)"
                    tooltiptext="${vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_APPLY_OVER_PAYMENT')}" visible="@load(vm.applyOverPaymentButton)" />
                <!-- <actionmenuitem label="@load(vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_ADD_CASHIER'))"
                    onClick="@command('accountPaymentButton',cmdButton='cbAddToCashier')"
                    tooltiptext="@load(vm.getText('AccountPaymentDetail:CB_ADD_CASHIER'))" /> -->
            </actionmenugroup>
        </actionmenu>
    </div>
</listcell>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi How we know issue from just image? please post some code.

Comment: How to set position so drop down will work fine

Comment: Added css used in the code

Comment: I think it's bootstrap dropdown menu. It's place inside listcell. am i right?

Comment: You can remove `float: left;` from your CSS, it's absolutely positioned with a `left` attribute, so the float isn't necessary as it's not floated.

Comment: But my issue is that when i am adding position: relative; then all items of Menu are not visible. While adding position: relative; also creating height issue in Cell

Comment: Type is previous comment If i am adding position: relative;  then Drop down showing fine but Listcell increasing its Height which is a issue ...While i am removing position: relative;  Drop down item hides

Comment: That's why I just posted it as a comment and not an answer :) - You should post some HTML so we can see how this appears in the code.

Comment: Removed excessive indentation.

Comment: @cfqueryparam  I did not catch your point